# Obtaining HTML and CSS code for this PayPal Button

Tags: paypal

I tried finding css code for the Paypal button shown in the image below via official site and many other third part sites. But I could not get it. Is there a way to get it?

[image]

Here you can find its actual script code:

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'buynow',
          
      },
      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{
                  amount: {
                      value: '1'
                  }
              }]
          });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
              alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
          });
      }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

That button is always rendered by `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js` -- the way to get it is in your question, use the script code, which opens a modern "in context" checkout window that keeps your site loaded in the background. See the interactive demo here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

You can find information about customizing the button at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/customize-button/

There is also a UI for styling at https://www.paypal.com/buttons/smart which could be used as a starting point

Comment: Honestly, I am not a coder. I am just trying to get help from coders like you. I hope you understand my point.

Comment: Well the answer is, everywhere you see that button it's from a `<script>`. You can generate one for your account at the last link provided.

Comment: I appreciate that, but my actual plan is to use smart checkout button css interface for direct paypal merchant link. So, I am finding it very difficult on that. I'd appreciate if you help me get it done.

Comment: I don't know what you just said means. But the best way to integrate a PayPal checkout is with the provided JavaScript, which renders the button and opens the checkout when clicked.